# App deployment failed in VS 2012 express edition for windows 8

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to run a windows 8 sample app on Visual studio 2012 express edition for windows 8.
I used web installer for VS and using windows 8 release preview build 8400.

I get this message even the app build is sucessful:
Error : DEP0800 : The required framework "F:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.WinJS.1.0\1.0\Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.appx" failed to install. 
Windows cannot install package Microsoft.WinJS.1.0 because this package requires a higher Windows version. The package requested Windows version 6.2 with AppModel version 1, while the current Windows version is 6.2 with AppModel version 0. App4

Any help?

Comment: I'll guess that you are using a preview version of Windows 8 instead of the RTM version.  You'll need to update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Visual Studio 2012 released version ([downloads here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads)) will work only with the RTM version of Windows 8, which is generally available on Oct. 26th, but a [90-day trial is available now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516.aspx).

The Windows 8 Release Preview is only compatible with Visual Studio 2012 RC, which I thought would be available until Windows 8 GA, but the [link I had for it](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29917) appears to now be broken.  You might be able to find a cached copy somewhere.